# Finding starts with text with Seleium IDE webdriver and python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I have the following code that was generated from Selenium IDE exporting to python / webdriver.  The problem I am having is the number in the parenthesis is dynamic and I have no idea what it will be.  However the first part "Company: Site" I have stored.

`Select(driver.find_element_by_id("id_customersite")).select_by_visible_text("Company: Site (15)")`

What I wanted to do is something like:

```
`Select(driver.find_element_by_id("id_customersite")).select_by_starswith("Company: Site")`
```

However I can't seem the correct syntax for doing this in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you would have to "manually" select the option using the "by xpath" locator and ["starts-with"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/starts-with) function:

```
select = driver.find_element_by_id("id_customersite")
option = select.find_element_by_xpath("//option[starts-with(., 'Company: Site')]")
option.click()
```